# Domain still alive after erasing it

Tags: apache, plesk

I have an new vps plesk server where I've migrated some domains.

One of them did some strange things and I decided to eliminate from plesk panel to try to migrate another time. After eliminating the site from plesk and (no files are in server) site still answer with the same error.

After reestarting plesk system and all of his instances and not having the domain in my panel. It's still answering. (I've validated the domain IP)

Sure it will be a silly question, but I'm really newbie in host administration: ¿Is there any hosting (apache or plesk) cache to reset?  ¿Something I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

As I said, it was a **silly question**.

My browsers (both) cahced the answer of the host. Four hours trashed for this stupid error. It's being a too-long weekend.